# exec with get method

Tags: php, post

I am running CentOS on my VPS (Linux) on PHP 5.3.15. I need to know how to post get data . When I go onto the page it's blank.

Here's the code:

First Attempt:

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$c = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$k = include("newb.php?a=$a&b=$b&c=$c&&d=$d");
exec("php newb.php?a=$a&b=$b&c=$c&&d=$d");
```

Second Attempt:

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$c = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$k = include("newb.php?a=$a&b=$b&c=$c&&d=$d");
exec("php $k");
```

Comment: Well, is there something in those fields? What do you see when you echo them?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? Do you just need your file to include newb.php, but newb.php expects $_GET params (and you only have $_POST params)?

Comment: newb.php excepts $_GET but i need to do it through exec.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a querystring for the include (for starters that doesn't work). The querystring is part of an URI. What you have there is not an URI it is just some filename.

The included file has access to the defined variables already.

P.S. The names you are giving to your variables aren't really clear and understandable ;)

P.P.S. What are you trying to do? Because there is almost certainly a way better way.

Answer (score 0):

The query string (the part with `?key=value`) is part of a URL. It only works from within your address bar. You cannot invoke command line scripts with query strings, and you cannot use them on included files.

- For included files, simply *include the file*, and it will have access to any varaibles you've declared:

  ```
  include("newb.php");
  ```
- For executed files, pass the arguments to the command exactly as you would on the command line: One at a time, separated by spaces:

  ```
  exec("php newb.php $a $b $c $d");
  ```

  Then, access them via `$argv`.

Note that you have a *serious* vulnerability in your code. You're passing arbitrary values to be executed on the command line. If an attacker posted `` "`rm -rf /`" `` to your program you would blindly delete every file on your server. You must **never** blindly execute user-submitted data as code, which is in effect what you're doing here.